# Como relacionar dois "models" com mongoose?

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, mongodb, mongoose

Eu tenho **dois** `models` no meu bd

**user.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

// User Model
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
  password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

UserSchema.add({
  email: 'string',
  about: 'string',
  age: 'number',
  active: 'Boolean',
  phone: 'number'
  });
```

e **actions.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

var ActionSchema = new Schema({
  postPerm: 'Boolean',
  sendEmailPerm: 'Boolean',
  editPerm: 'Boolean'
});
```

*Como faço para relaciona-los?*

No caso eu quero que todo **USER** tenha uma **ACTIONS** *relacionado* onde eu farei o controle delas

Comment: Link com boas respostas sobre relacionamentos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245685/mongoose-one-to-many/35245953

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O mais próximo que o MongoDB pode ter com banco relacional é o uso de [Reference](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), onde é possível criar referência entre documentos.

> No caso eu quero que todo USER tenha uma ACTIONS relacionado

MongoDB é um NoSQL e não tem algo como *constraint* de campo obrigatória entre chave primária e estrangeira a nível de banco, entretanto mongoose tem o middleware [validation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) que ajuda em algumas tarefas como essa (no seu caso específico, para não salvar uma action sem user, ou vice-versa).

### Exemplo da reference

```
[...]
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
  password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
  actions: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Action' }] // aqui é feita a referencia entre os documentos
});

var ActionSchema = new Schema({
  postPerm: 'Boolean',
  sendEmailPerm: 'Boolean',
  editPerm: 'Boolean'
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
var Action = mongoose.model('Action', ActionSchema);
```